# Is it an approval or disapproval?

Tags: word-usage

In following sentence:

> From the perspective of a ‘cyber warrior’, cyber crime can offer the technical basis
>   and cyber terrorism the social basis with which to execute nationally sanctioned attacks on the computer networks of enemy groups or nations.
>
> — *National Cyber Security Framework Manual,* NATO Cooperative Cyber Defence Centre of Excellence, Tallinn ([PDF](https://ccdcoe.org/publications/books/NationalCyberSecurityFrameworkManual.pdf), 3.8MB)

What does 'nationally sanctioned attacks' mean? Is it going to approve attacks throughout the country and cyber attacks against enemies are nationally allowed?
Or does it mean 'attacks which are sanctioned inside, but can be used as a tool for foreign affairs'?

Comment: The question is not about the English language. The implication of the phrase in question depends on context and interpretation. This question is to be asked on a related Q&A site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sanctioned* can be confusing in that there is a contradiction between its meaning "approved of and allowed" and its meaning "punished".

However, while these are opposed, they are not diametrically so.

*Sanction* does not have a meaning of "disapprove", though the punishment would come due to disapproval.

*Sanction* does not have a meaning of "reward", though approval might lead to a reward.

And in the context of this, "execute nationally punished attacks" makes little sense, while "execute nationally authorised attacks" does.

So it means "approve-of" or "authorised" here.